# How can use NetLogo to simulate the outcome of a function

Tags: netlogo

assuming I got a function like Y= 0.5*a+0.23*b+0.52*c+0.3

a is a continuous variable, b and c are categorical variables(like 1 or 0)

I wanna create multiple agents that can hatch the number of Y (round up to an integer) with different b and c

Honestly, I am new to Netlogo and I am not very familiar with coding.

I went through the three tutorials of the user manual, but I still have no clue to do that.

three tutorials of the user manual.

Thank you

Comment: Where do the values of b and c come from? For example, do you want random numbers from a distribution, or values provided by the user?

Comment: Thank you. My idea is the values of a,b and c will be decided by the sliders on interface. Is that sounds work?

Comment: To be more specific, Y can be viewed as the number of other agents can be created by the initial turtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you said. But I don't think it's actually what you mean.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  let a 5
  let b 10
  let c 20
  let Y ceiling (0.5 * a + 0.23 * b + 0.52 * c + 0.3)
  print Y
  create-turtles Y
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is an inspiration!